# Can you replace a CPU-controlled character with a human in Super Mario Party?

Tags: super-mario-party

I was wondering if you could **replace a CPU-controlled character during a local game with a human-controlled character.**

For example if I am playing with 2 friends on the normal "Mario Party" game mode (traditional 4-player battle) and a third friend wants to play with us (local game, not online, the friend is physically with us): can I replace one of the two CPUs with my third friend?

Comment: I dont think this is possible. I remember you could in the classic versions like MP 1 and 2 for the 64, but after playing the game myself for a quite a bit, I havent seen anything in the settings menu during a game that lets you alter who is a computer and who isnt. I bet it is because you choose characters and CPUs before choosing a gamemode, its probably something related to the code that made this impossible. Even just to switch that around after a game you have to completely back out to the start menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having played the game myself for quite a bit, I have tried this too and was not able to find anything in the settings menu during a game. Im not sure the exact reason, I remember being able to do this in the N64 Mario Party's, but Im guessing its relating to the fact that you choose Characters and CPU's before you even get into the world to start a game. The only way to change this is to back out to the start menu.